# Testing List<Map> with mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to test a List with mockito but do not know how to set my expected value.

Below is what I have so far. Also if someone can tell me how to create mock objects with specific values that would be awesome.

```
@Test
public void testFindAllProductsByCategoryId() throws Exception {
    List<Map> expectedProductList =  anyList(Products.class);
    when(productListMock.findAllProductsByCategoryId(1)).thenReturn(expectedProductList);
    List<Map> actualProductList = productListMock.findAllProductsByCategoryId(1);
}
```

Comment: What is your System Under Test here?  What are you actually trying to test?  Are you aware that mockito has an `anyList()` method?  You're confusing your example by using that in your code.  Is that your method or mockito's?

Comment: I am trying to test the return of multiple objects when the findByCategory method is found.  I tried using the anyList() method but I am having trouble getting it to work. It is my first day with mockito and I am trying to learn what I can.

Comment: I think you haven't understood what mocking is used for. If your goal is to test the result of `findAllProductsByCategoryId()`, then you must NOT mock this method (and the object containing it). If you do that, the only thing your test will do is verify that mockito does what you tell it to do. mocking a method consists in telling: don't do what you normally do, but do this instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're doing this right.  [anyList is for matchers.](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html)  you're supposed to use it inside the `when` method.  For example:

```
    when(mockedObject.methodIsCalledWith(anyList())).thenReturn(...);
```

That said, I don't have a clear idea of what you're trying to do here.  [The documentation of mockito](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html) is **very** well written so I think you should go back to that to figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: This helped me down the right path, however I made some tweaks.  Also do you think you can remove the vote Down?